# Folder creation in parallel in a FOR loop python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Is there anyway i can have the below folder creation happen in parallel rather than iterate?
I tried with multiprocessing and it seems to be not working. Any suggestions welcome.

```py
import os
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing

def foldercreation(foldername):
    target_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Myna\\Desktop\\Cisco'
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(target_dir,foldername))

n=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
print(n)
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n) as p:
    for i in ['A','B','C','D']:
        foldercreation(i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the pool.

Here's an example:

```py
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n) as p:
    p.map(foldercreation, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was able to fix it. Now i am trying to pass 2 parameters for folder creation and it keeps on failing. Something like below is the code.if __name__ =='__main__':
    n=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    print(n)
    seq=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','i','j']
    seq1=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','i','j']
    #list(map(foldercreation,seq,seq1))
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n) as p:
        list(p.map(foldercreation,seq,seq1))

Comment: Why do you need to pass 2 lists instead of passing a single consolidated list or invoking the `p.map` function twice, each time with a different list?

Comment: I need to build the folder name based on 2 lists. I was able to do it using starmap() method. Thanks.